# Laravel 5.2 - Syncing when empty array not working?

Tags: php, laravel-5, pivot-table

I have the following function:

```
private function syncTags(Profile $profile, array $tags)
{
    $profile->tags()->sync($tags);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$this->syncTags($profile, $request->input('tags'));
```

But it is throwing error:

```
Argument 2 passed to syncTags() must be of the type array, null given
```

This is happening when I don't select any tags. The tags is a checkbox list that a user can check/uncheck. How can I fix?

I've tried the following which makes no difference either:

```
$profile->tags()->sync((array) $tags);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use collection or the request instance just use

```
$profile->tags()->sync($request->get('tags', []))
```

otherwise do this

```
$profile->tags()->sync(($tags) ? $tags : [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to sometimes call `syncTags()` without any tags, you can make the second argument optional by providing a default value:

```
private function syncTags(Profile $profile, array $tags = [])
```

This will allow you do to both this:

```
$obj->syncTags($profile, $tags);
```

And this:

```
$obj->syncTags($profile);
```

Though I'm not so sure what the point of the latter would be, since you'd be syncing nothing. (Unless perhaps that method syncs everything if no specific tags are provided.)

Comment: I may want to pass an empty array to remove tags but changing the parameter signature to `array $tags = []` makes no difference. For the tags I have a bunch of checkboxes, when they are unchecked and I call the above function it fails with the aforementioned error?